# RegExp - Replace some characters between <td> markups

Tags: javascript, regex, markup

I coded an AJAX function to make a search engine in a database. I want to highlight in yellow the searched characters in the displayed result.

The following code is working pretty well:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "search_db.php",
    data: "q="+valueSearch,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(returnQuery) {
        $("#table tbody").empty();
        // console.log(returnQuery);
        $.each(returnQuery, function(i, line) {
            content = '<tr>';
            content += '<td>' + line.name_serv + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + line.name_dns + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + line.ip + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + line.pass1 + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + line.pass2 + '</td>';
            content += '</tr>';

            re = new RegExp('('+valueSearch+')', "gi")
            content2 = content.replace(re, '<span style="background-color: #ffff66;">$1</span>');

            $(content2).appendTo("#table tbody");
        });
    }, 
    error: function() {
        $("#table tbody").empty();
    }
});
```

There are three cases where it doesn't work properly: if I search '**d**', '**t**' or '**r**' (because the remplacements are made in the `<td>` or `<tr>` markups too).

Here is an example of the variable *content*:
`"<tr><td>Jupiter</td><td>mail.test.com</td><td>10.0.0.1</td><td>root</td><td>a$01'deK</td></tr>"`

I try to make a RegExp to add the `<span>` markup only to characters matching the search between `<td>` and `</td>`, but I don't find the right syntax.

Does anyone have an idea (pure JavaScript and/or jQuery)?

Comment: Rule 1: don't use RegEx to parse HTML. Rule 2: if you still want to parse HTML with RegEx, see rule 1.  [RegEx can only match regular languages, and HTML is not a regular language](http://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/930393)

Comment: Further to @freefaller's comment and not doing this with regex:  You're already using jQuery, so a good approach would be to wrap up `content` and use jQuery functionality to handle this: `$(content).find(....)` etc.

Comment: Why are you not matching the text when you are building the cells?

Comment: @freefaller He doesn't want to parse HTML, he wants to perform replacements everywhere but in tags, and regexes are an appropriate tool for that. Besides, modern regexes aren't regular anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to run the regular expression BEFORE embedding the lines into td's, and do it on each line individually. I would create a function inside of the ajax call like this:

```js
highlightMatches(line, valueSearch))
{

re = new RegExp('('+valueSearch+')', "gi")
line2 = line.replace(re, '<span style="background-color: #ffff66;">$1</span>');

  return line2;
}



line.name_serv = highlightMatches(line.name_serv, valueSearch)
line.name_dns  = highlightMatches(line.name_dns, valueSearch)
.
.
.
.
```

THEN I'd wrap each of the lines into content just as you've done.

That's my approach at least.

Comment: I chose this solution, thanks! It was the easiest one and it answers my need. `valueSearch` must be a parameter of the function though (I called the function like this: `highlightMatches(line.name_serv, valueSearch)`).

Comment: Thanks! I had fun writing it. Also thanks for the upgrade, I'll edit the code to match your function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified approach to highlight all occurences of `t` outside of tags:

```js
content = content.replace(/<.*?>|(t)/gi, function(match, captured) {
  if (!captured)
    return match;

  return '<span class="hl">' + captured + '</span>';
});
```

You can easily generalize this approach, just don't forget to escape the regex metacharacters:

```js
function highlightTextInHtml(content, search) {
  // Escape regex metacharacters
  search = search.replace(/[-\\()\[\]{}^$*+.?|]/g, '\\$&');
  
  // Build the regex
  var re = new RegExp("<.*?>|(" +search+ ")", "gi");
  
  // Highlight matches
  return content.replace(re, function(match, captured) {
    if (!captured)
      return match;

    return '<span class="hl">' + captured + '</span>';
  });
}

$(document).on("ready", function() {
  var originalContent = $("#content").html();

  $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    $("#content").html(highlightTextInHtml(originalContent, $("#search").val()));
  }).triggerHandler("keyup");
});
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid black; }
.hl { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    Search for: <input type="text" id="search" value="t"/>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <table>
    <tr><td>Jupiter</td><td>mail.test.com</td><td>10.0.0.1</td><td>root</td><td>a$01'deK</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't try your answer because @Benshums's one seems easier to me. Thanks a lot for the effort though!

Comment: No worries, his approach is better in your case. I posted this to answer the question *literally*, it could be useful for people who have a HTML string from an external source for instance.

Comment: But you still should add `valueSearch = valueSearch.replace(/[-\\()\[\]{}^$*+.?|]/g, '\\$&');` to his solution to escape the metacharacters, especially if `valueSearch` comes from an external source like user input: try searching for `a$01`.